# TypeError: Cannot read property 'unlink' of undefined at Grid.remove

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, gridfs

I'm trying to create a delete button, by which if I press it, I can delete a file from the server directly. I'm implementing it by fridFsStore.

```
// @desc  Delete file
app.delete('/files/:id', (req, res) => {
    gfs.remove({ _id: req.params.id, root: 'uploads' }, (err, gridStore) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(404).json({ err: err });
      }
  
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
```

But it's showing an error as -

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'unlink' of undefined
> at Grid.remove

Comment: Hello, were you able to solve this, I have same issue